# Newbie in Java. Found "For+Scanner" strange behavior

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

In a Java studying process, i found a strange behavior in my program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            strings.add(scanner.nextLine());
            System.out.println(strings.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(strings.size());

    }
}
```

Current example works OK, as a result i see correct input result.
But, if i remove my checking string `System.out.println(strings.get(i));`, program allows me to make only 2 keyboard inputs against 3. And also it automatically inputs empty string on the second step of cycle.

Example:
[image: example]

So, why does it happen and how to avoid it?

Comment: Are you maybe calling any other methods on the scanner (like nextInt() for example) in between your nextLine() calls that you didn't include in the code of your question?

Comment: I don't see why the current loop would shrink by 1 if you comment the printing statement. You will be still able to add your inputs to the string list, i.e. 3 inputs but you won't display them iteratively. You can display the whole list after the for loop and make sure all the elements are there. The size still will be 3.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS
I've added all code of my program

Comment: In that case I cannot reproduce your problem at all: https://ideone.com/WGDWIt - As you see i removed the line you claim removing causes your error, but the list still ends up with a size of 3.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS
Seems i have some bug in the IDEA, because here is my output results:

https://ibb.co/m6TdrbH

Comment: @user16320675, i've downloaded EclipseIDE. And seems the problem only in the IDE tool, because in the Eclipse it works OK

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was in an IDE. I've downloaded Eclipse and the problem wasn't reproduced there. Thanks to all who tried to help!
Here is the info about problem IDE:

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-221.5591.52, built on May 10, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.45 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.jetbrains.edu (2022.5-2022.1-343)

Kotlin: 221-1.6.21-release-337-IJ5591.52

Comment: I don't believe IDEA has an issue here. Saying the specific IDE version is the problem without understanding how/why the problem is occurring is premature. Your project has settings for "Project SDK" within IDEA - is it pointing at the same JDK your Eclipse IDE uses?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).